# passing parameters in post request axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i have an object that i will use in post request using axios

```
employee:{
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test@gmail.com',
    password: '123456',
    role: {
       created_at:"2018-08-03 07:34:30"
       deleted_at:null
       id:2
       role_name:"employee"
       updated_at:"2018-08-03 07:34:30"
    }
},
```

this is my post request

```
axios.post('api/employees', vm.employee)
.then( response => {
    alert("Employee Inserted");
    vm.errors.clear();
    vm.setFalse();
    vm.fetchEmployees();
    })
    .catch( error => {
       vm.errors.record(error.response.data);
});
```

how can I pass in post request only the role_name in role object together with name, email and password

Answer (score 0):

If you mean headers by parameters then you can try:

```
var options = {
  headers: {'X-My-Custom-Header': 'Header-Value'}
};

axios.post('api/employees', vm.employee, options);
```

Other wise just create a a body like this:

```
var options = {
  headers: {'X-My-Custom-Header': 'Header-Value'}
};

axios.post('api/employees', { 
  name: vm.employee.name, 
  role: { 
    role_name: vm.employee.role.role_name 
  } 
}, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this work for you.

```
axios.post('api/employees', {name: employee.name, email: employee.email, role_name: employee.role.role_name})
.then( response => {
    alert("Employee Inserted");
    vm.errors.clear();
    vm.setFalse();
    vm.fetchEmployees();
    })
    .catch( error => {
       vm.errors.record(error.response.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If ES2015 is ok then this would be a shorter way to pass the data:

```
axios.post('api/employees', {
  ...employee,
  role: { role_name: employee.role.role_name }
}) ...
```